# Docker - Can't push on my registry when using S3 configuration

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-s3, docker

I'm trying to set up my own docker registry on a amazon ec2.

If I launch it such as:

```
docker run -p 5000:5000 registry
```

it's working without any problem.

However when I try to launch it with s3 using my credential such as:

```
docker run -p 5000:5000 -e SETTINGS_FLAVOR=s3 -e AWS_REGION=eu-west-1 -e AWS_BUCKET=$BUCKET -e STORAGE_PATH=/registry -e AWS_KEY=$AWS_KEY -e AWS_SECRET=$AWS_SECRET registry
```

I get

```
alexis@ubuntu:/home/web$ sudo docker push amazon.ip:5000/web
2014/10/07 00:57:38 Error: Invalid Registry endpoint: Get http://amazon.ip:5000/v1/_ping: dial tcp amazon.ip:5000: connection refused
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Did the container crash on startup? (try `docker ps`) What does its output look like? (try `docker logs registry`)

Comment: no nothing crash I just have `2014-10-07 08:20:50,194 WARNING: Cache storage disabled!
2014-10-07 08:20:50,195 WARNING: LRU cache disabled!` in the log as if gunicorn is not starting

Comment: Oh, now that I think about it, I had this issue before, too. Specifying a region seems to break the registry. There's an issue open here: https://github.com/docker/docker-registry/issues/400 — not fixed yet though. Removing the region fixed it for me, but your mileage may vary.